# Hibernate HQL query with boolean attibute and SAP HANA DB

Tags: java, hibernate

Goodmoring

I have the following situation.

I have a model with a boolean attribute

```
  @Column(name = "ELIMINATO") 
  private Boolean eliminato;
```

and the following HQL query on it

```
Query q =  session.createQuery("from Sottoscrittore where eliminato = false");
```

Hibernate generates the following SQL query

```
select
    ... all fields ...
from
    SOTTOSCRITTORE modulounic0_ 
where
    modulounic0_.ELIMINATO=0
```

When I run this query the following error is returned

```
SAP DBTech JDBC: [266]: inconsistent datatype: INT type is not comparable with BOOLEAN type.
```

The problem is that in SAP HANA DB the correct query is the following

```
select
    ... all fields ...
from
    SOTTOSCRITTORE 
where
    ELIMINATO=FALSE;
```

To set the right value of the query I tried to set the hibernate property
"hibernate.query.substitutions" in "hibernate.cfg.xml" in this way

```
<property name="hibernate.query.substitutions">true TRUE, false FALSE</property>
```

but I had the same error.

It could be a Hibernate framework bug?

How can I solve the problem?

Thanks

Regards

Comment: What hibernate dialect do you use?

Comment: This is the dialect that I use "org.hibernate.dialect.HANAColumnStoreDialect"

Answer (score 0):

just add following property in your persistence.xml file:

```
<property name="hibernate.dialect.hana.use_legacy_boolean_type" value="false"/>
```